# how to parse json-ld file with rdflib.parse() or load()

Tags: json-ld, rdflib

I am new to json-ld and rdflib usage. I have json-ld file with @context and @graph sections inside.
I want to use rdflib open to load this graph. 
When I try using parse() method, with format='n3', I am getting error

`BadSyntax: at line 5 of <>:
Bad syntax (expected '.' or '}' or ']' at end of statement) at ^ in:`

If I give format='json-ld', it says No plugin registered for (json-ld, )

If I don't give any format parameter then it says,
SAXParseException: file:composition.json-ld:1:0: not well-formed (invalid token)

`rdflib.Graph().load('composition.json-ld')`
`Error SAXParseException: not well-formed (invalid token)`

`rdflib.Graph().load('composition.json-ld', format='json-ld')`
`Error PluginException: No plugin registered for (json-ld, <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)`

`f= open('filename.json-ld', 'rb')`
`rdflib.Graph().parse(data=f.read(), format='json-ld') ==> Error PluginException: No plugin registered for (json-ld, <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)`

I checked json-ld file in json-ld playground. It is correct.
Am I missing something in syntax for parsing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the [JSON-LD plugin](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-jsonld)? If not, do a

```
pip install rdflib-jsonld
```

Comment: Oh. I thought it is already included when I installed rdflib with pip. Thanks for this.